# Runtime error 91: Variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Admittedly, a lot of this code is copy-pasted from other help threads.

The code is going through Sheets("programs") and looking at the value in Column H. Depending on that value, it will either look for another sheet with the corresponding name and put the entire row in it, or if the sheet does not exist, it will make the sheet and put the row in it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fr33M4cro()

    Dim sh33tname As String
    Dim custNameColumn As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim stRow As Long
    Dim customer As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetExist As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wsRow As Long
    Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
    Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range, NmSTR As String

    sh33tname = "programs"
    custNameColumn = "H"
    stRow = 3

    Set wsTEMP = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set sh = Sheets(sh33tname)
    Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)

    For i = stRow To sh.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        customer = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If StrComp(ws.Name, customer, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                sheetExist = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If sheetExist Then
            CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn, wsRow
        Else
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range(custNameColumn & i).Value
            CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn, wsRow
        End If
        Reset sheetExist
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CopyRow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, custNameColumn As String, wsRow As Long)
    wsRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    sh.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
    ws.Rows(wsRow & ":" & wsRow).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Reset(ByRef x As Boolean)
    x = False
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSheet(shName As String)
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = shName
End Sub



Function FixStringForSheetName(shSTR As String) As String

'replace each forbidden character with something acceptable
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, ":", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "?", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "*", "")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "/", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "\", "-")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "[", "(")
    shSTR = Replace(shSTR, "]", ")")

'sheet names can only be 31 characters
    FixStringForSheetName = Trim(Left(shSTR, 31))

End Function
```

The problem i'm having is that it will make a new sheet with the value of Column H, but then "run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set at the line". If i end the macro and restart it without changing anything, it will populate all the rows for that first sheet that was made last time, make a new sheet for the next value of Column H, and Run-Time error 91 again.
It points to this line of code.

```
wsRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

From what I gather, I've declared wsRow As Long in the first part, but I never set it as something. Because i'm a newbie, I'm not sure what to set it as that won't interfere with the rest of the script.

Comment: You need to declare `wsRow` outside your first procedure, otherwise its scope is limited to the first one only http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Scope.aspx

Comment: That said, not sure if that would cause your RTE.

Comment: I have tried putting `Dim wsRow as Long` and `Set wsRow = 0` where I set the other variables, without success

Comment: No I just meant the line `Dim wsRow as Long` should be before the `Sub Fr33M4cro()` line. I think Jeeped has hit on the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new worksheet, you do not have it associated with the ws worksheet var. You use ActiveSheet to assign the name; use ActiveSheet to provide a target for the CopyRow.

```
    ...
    If sheetExist Then
        CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn, wsRow
    Else
        wsTEMP.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range(custNameColumn & i).Value
        CopyRow i, sh, ActiveSheet, custNameColumn, wsRow
    End If
    ...
```

Comment: Changing to this, the macro then moves the first row to the new sheet, but is attempting to make a new sheet by the same name. which gives error 1004, duplicate name. It doesn't look at 
`If sheetExist Then
CopyRow i, sh, ws, custNameColumn, wsRow`